# How to find the diagonal elements of a matrix?

Tags: r

I have written a function to store the diagonal elements of a matrix into a vector. but the output is not as I expected. The code is:

```
diagonal <- function(x) {
  for (i in nrow(x)) {
    for (j in ncol(x)) {
      if (i == j) {
        a <- x[i, j]
      }
    }
  }
  print(a)
}
```

I am passing a matrix to the function.
What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing diagonal elements from matrix in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839090/removing-diagonal-elements-from-matrix-in-r)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use the `diag` function

```
diag(m1)
#[1] 1 5 9
```

Or

```
m1[col(m1)==row(m1)]
#[1] 1 5 9
```

---

If we are using the `for` loop, we are looping by the sequence of rows and columns i.e `1:nrow(x)/1:ncol(x)` and not by `nrow(x)/ncol(x)`.

```
diagonal <- function(x) {
  a <- numeric(0)
 for( i in 1:nrow(x)){ 
  for(j in 1:ncol(x)){
     if(i == j) { 
       a <-  c(a, x[i,j])
     } 
    }
  }
 a
 }

diagonal(m1)
#[1] 1 5 9
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3)
```

Comment: I am aware of the diag() function. I am a beginner at R. so was practicing to write functions

Comment: Better to pre-allocate and fill `a`, rather than terrible performance copy-and-append -- `n = min(nrow(x), ncol(x)); a = numeric(n)`. Rather than iterating over rows / columns that cannot satisfy the condition, why not `for (i in seq_len(n)) a[i] = x[i, i]`?

Comment: @MartinMorgan You are right.  I was just showing a way to correct the OP's code with minimal interventions.

Comment: plus one just for `m1[col(m1)==row(m1)]`